# Prove that the intersection of two subgroups forms a specific subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We consider the groups $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$, ($n, m \in \mathbb{N}^*$), which are subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. Prove that $n\mathbb{Z} \, \cap \, m\mathbb{Z} = [n, m]\mathbb{Z}$, where $[n, m]$ is the least common multiple of $n$ and $m$.

I need some advice on how to start solving this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in [n,m]\Bbb{Z}$. Then $x=[n,m]k$ for some integer $k$, since $[n,m]$ is multiple of $n$ and $m$, so $x\in n\Bbb{Z}$ and $x\in \Bbb{Z}$. Thus $x\in n\Bbb{Z}\cap m\Bbb{Z}$.

Let $x\in n\Bbb{Z}\cap m\Bbb{Z}$. Then $x=np=mq$ for some integers $p$ and $q$. Since $x$ is a multiple of both $n$ and $m$, by the definition of least common multiple, $x$ is a multiple of $[n,m]$, that is $x=[n,m]c$ for some integer $c$. Thus, $x\in [n,m]\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $d\mathbb{Z}$ for a unique non-negative integer $d$.

So writing $n\mathbb{Z}\cap m\mathbb{Z}=l\mathbb{Z}$, you just have to show that $l$ has the properties which characterize the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$, namely that it is divisible by both $m$ and $n$, and divides any other common multiple of $m$ and $n$.